# spring bean skip auto wire for collection declared inside component

Tags: java, spring

The below is my code, because of the blocking queue no such bean exception is coming. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue. How to ignore than auto wiring for queue? i need to use the genericServiceImpl class by autowiring. I have added parameter less constructor and checked it did not work.

```
@Component
public class Task {

    @Autowired
    private GenericServiceImpl genericServiceImpl;

    private BlockingQueue<String> queue = null;

    public Task(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
  }

    private void task() {
      genericServiceImpl.findAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: You could add the `autowire` annotation on the construcotr and set `required=false`. Although I'd remove the current constructor in favour of an autowired setter. Generally constructors are for required dependencies, setters optional, field autowiring should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have any `public constructor` by which Spring can `instantiate` `Task` object other than `Task(BlockingQueue<String> queue)`. So, when spring tries to `instantiate` the Task object it will try to find bean of `BlockingQueue` as it needs to pass (the only public constructor). You can solve the problem by adding an empty `constructor`

```
public Task() { }
```

or providing a binding of  `BlockingQueue`

I am not sure why you are using `BlockingQueue` as I can't find any use of that as per your posted code.

Comment: thanks, I tried parameter less constructor it didn't work i mentioned in my post itself, blocking queue i am using it that it is unnecessary code to post, to describe a problem this is enough i thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Spring works. If you class has only one constructor then Spring tries to use it to create your bean. And in this case it tries to find all its arguments in context to autowire. Obviously there is no bean of type `BlockingQueue<String>` declared in context or configuration class.

If you really need to pass that queue as a parameter I'd better make your class accepting two parameters in constructor

```
public Task(GenericServiceImpl genericServiceImpl, BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
    //.....
}
```

and also make `Task` class simple class without any Spring annotations on it.
In this case you will need to create instances of this class manually like this

```
@Service
class AnotherService {

    private Task task;

    public AnotherService(GenericServiceImpl genericServiceImpl) [
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = ....;
        task = new Task(genericServiceImpl, queue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as of now i have done like this only, i feel its not correct way to do this, i have tried with  the parameterless constructor also but it didn't work.  public Task() {
  this.queue = null;
 }